# MongoDB is not using multikey index with array of documents

Tags: mongodb

I have the following multi key index defined on my mongo collection:

```
{
    "array_field.k" : 1,
    "array_field.v" : 1,
    "date" : 1,
   */Other fields */
}
```

The documents are like this:

```
{ "array_field": [ { "k": "key1", "v": "value1"}, {"k": "key2", "v": "value2"} ], "date": ISODate("2022-06-20") }
```

Then I make a find query like this:

```
{
   date: { $gte: ISODate("2022-06-20") },
   array_field: { "k": "key1", "v": "value1"}
}
```

or even:

```
{
   date: { $gte: ISODate("2022-06-20") },
   array_field.k: "key1",
   array_field.v: "value1",
}
```

the index statistics show that the index is not being used.

I am using MongoDB 4.2 and according to documentation this should be working:

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.2/core/index-multikey/

What I am doing wrong?

@Tom Slabbaert This is the `inputStage` on the winning plan, seems my `array_field` is not being used in the plan, only the date field (Which is in fact a different index)

[image: winningPlan]

@Alex Blex. This query is enough to see that the index is not being used

```
db.my_col.find({
    "array_field.k": "key1",
    "array_field.v": "value1",
    date: {
        $gte: ISODate("2022-06-20T22:00:00.000Z"),
        $lt: ISODate("2022-06-21T22:00:00.000Z")
    }
    
}).explain("queryPlanner")
```

In the real scenario, where I am using the Java API, I am using more fields to make and aggregation after the find, but abstracting to the match part of the query, which is this, I already can see the index is not being used.

If I run `.explain("queryPlanner")` I can see the index is discarded as stated in the image below (Please note `filters_lst` is the real name of my array field:

[image]

Comment: Can you post the results of `explain` to see which index (if any) is being used? it sounds like a different index is being selected for the query.

Comment: Please add the whole query. Do you use aggregation or sorting?  Was the index considered in "rejectedPlans" when you run `explain("queryPlanner")` ? There are many things that may affect query planner, but in most cases if the index is rejected, it means it is less efficient in this query. If you insist, you can always force an index with `.hint()`

Comment: @AlexBlex So if the index appears in the reject plans does it mean that it could be used but mongo discarded it for performance reasons?

Comment: yes, you should go read about how mongo "choose a winning plan" - there are plenty of stack overflow questions about this topic.  basically Mongo performs a small race between all viable candidates. depending on which documents are sampled can affect which index is selected. I recommend you use "hint" to overcome this issue here

Comment: Precisely. There are complex explanations about index selectivity, availability, and other factors, but to put it simple, the query optimiser just run short queries and calculates amount of work units spent, then picks the cheapest. In rare cases with uneven data distribution it may result with less optimal choice, hence the hint() option.  Ironically on the second screenshot the date_1 index was actually rejected. I guess the difference in index performance is marginal and is not consistent.

Comment: @AlexBlex Yep, I probably get confused when I saw that picture and I though the rejected index was de multikey index, but not. But I am reapiting it and I can see the multikey is rejected.   Thanks

Comment: It's normal, as I said, if there is no major difference in performance, Mongo can use either index depending on secondary factors. There is nothing wrong with index definition on your side.  You can combine .hint() and .eval("executionStats") to compare speed for both indices.

Answer (score 0):

The field order metter when you use indexes , you either need to change the order in the find() query or the index field order , for example:

```
index : { date:1 , array_field.k:1,array_field.v:1 }
```

will be working for find query:

```
db.collection.find(date:x, array_field.k:y )
```

For your current index following query:

```
 {
 date: { $gte: ISODate("2022-06-20") },
  array_field: { "k": "key1", "v": "value1"}
 }
```

need to be changed as follow:

```
{  
 "array_field.k": "key1",
 "array_field.v":"value1",
  date: { $gte: ISODate("2022-06-20") }

}
```

also for multikey index there is difference between:

```
 "array_field.k": "key1",
 "array_field.v":"value1"
```

and:

```
 "array_field:{"k": "key1","v":"value1"}
```

( in this case your current index will not be used )

Comment: It matters only in sort(), not in find()

Comment: Yep, field order does not affect in that case. Just tried with a different collection where the first field is an array of string instead of objects, and that index is used regardless the position of the array field and the date field.

Comment: hmm , interesting , just reproduced in my lab and I can confirm the above mentioned , maybe there is some differences on what we do , maybe because testing in 4.2 ..